# Django - User not getting logged in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using JWT authentication for my django-rest-framework and react project. So, I have defined a **URL** path that provides the **JWT** token.

```
path('api/auth/token/', obtain_jwt_token),
```

I have defined another path which retrieves the **current logged-in user**:

```
path('current_user/', current_user, name='current-user'),
```

**current_user**:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return Response('User is not authenticated') 
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) 
    serializer = CurrentProfileSerializer(profile)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem is, after I log in at `api/auth/token/` and then go to `current_user/`, I am getting **'User is not authenticated'** response. I thought that `obtain_jwt_token` returns a **token** and **logs in the user** to `request.user`. Am I wrong for assuming this? Please ask if I need to provide any more details.

---

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: What is your authentication scheme? do you have it configured globally in settings.py (DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES)?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you receive token in ***api/auth/token*** reuqest, you should store it in frontend. then in ***currect_user*** request, use this stored token in header of request. like this:

```
Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFsaUBtYWlsLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTUzMzcxNjUzNCwiZW1haWwiOiJhbGlAbWFpbC5jb20ifQWfVfp6Nfj9gvedTkqhqlwZhAwzi2YK64cx2FpRLms
```

Comment: This works, but can u tell why this should be done like this?

Comment: There is different between session authentication and token authentication. token authentication usually use in systems, that client is not a computer, for example client is an android device, or client is angular app. you can research about token auth, and I refer you to this link : https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-scalable-user-mgmt